# SSRS date format in Excel with localization

Tags: excel, date, reporting-services, localization, format

I'm trying to export a SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services report to Excel. The report has a column of dates. The date is stored as a datetime in the SQL server.
The language of the report is set to `=User!Language`, the format of the date-cell is `d`.
When exporting/rendering the report to PDF, everything is displayed in the locale of the request made by the browser (`Accept-Language`).

When rendering to Excel however, the format suddenly changes, for example, to `General ([$-10409]M.T.JJJJ)` (German Excel, locale of the OS set to `de-AT`, browser-locale is `en-US`).

This means that the Excel displays dates in a completely wrong format - the sequence of day, month and year is hardcoded and only the separator comes from the current locale. This makes sharing reports between different OS languages almost impossible since a report generated from a `d-m-yyyy` country will still display as day-month-year in a country with different date formatting (and vice versa). So any person expecting a `m/d/yyyy` formatted date will get `d/m/yyyy`.

This is especially dangerous if there are no dates with days above 12 - ie: it is very likely to misread the displayed date because there is no obvious error.

When manually setting the cell-format in Excel to date, everything seems fine and the format changes with the locale of the OS.

Is there any possibility to force the cell to be formatted as Date in Excel without having to edit the Excel file itself?

P.S: numbers are also not formatted as a number but as `[$-10409]#.##0,00;-#.##0,00` - which is less of an issue but still potentially a source of errors. (format in the report is `N2`)

Comment: Can you change the os language?

Comment: Changing the OS language is how I found out about this. Excel displays cells in the correct language-dependent format if the cell itself is formatted as date. Of course it doesn't help that SSRS generates the cells with a custom format where the position of day, month and year remains static.

Comment: I'm  not from a server background but that seems like the issue. The server seems to have other ideas of your user language.

Comment: @glh the server receives the language from the browser (`Accept-Language` header) and the report language is `=User!Language`. Therefore the generation on the server-side happens with the language of the browser. The numeric and date fields however should be displayed in the locale of the OS. The separators are taken from the OS language but NOT the ordering (because SSRS introduces a custom format for these cells?!). I can't force the report to generate dates and numbers as string because that would make the Excel file pretty useless - so I want number/date instead of "General" (custom).

Comment: Have you found solution?

Answer (score -1):

I've manages to solve similiar issue. Solution is rather simple.
 In report editor, open Design view and select field, which you want to edit, right mouse click and choosee either `Expression` or `Textbox properties`. The rest is very intuitive as in Excel editor.

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to see a solution to the problem that the format of the date fields is locale/language-dependent in Excel exports. While it is possible to set the format in the `Textbox properties` in the `Number` settings to `Date`, this does not result in the cells being formatted as `Date` but as `General` with hardcoded date format.

Comment: It is hardcoded date format, because in other case it will denitely be dependent on locale information. Unfotunately there is no other option, unless you write your own rendering machinery for SSRS.

Comment: in an Excel file I expect dates to be locale/language dependent. Excel has the option to format cells as `Date` for this very reason. There is a huge difference if the date is `01.12.2013` or `12.01.2013` with no indication if it is `m.d.yyyy` or `d.m.yyyy`. For business reports this could have catastrophic effects.